# yii2 : Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i try to send an email in yii2 project in server but showing error Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)

my config is this

```
'mailer' => [  //Your default mailer
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

and my code is

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom('info@gmail.com')
->setTo('text@gmail.com')
->setSubject('Subject')
->setTextBody('Plain text content')
->setHtmlBody("Hello")
->send();
```

Comment: can you try using ssl instead of tls

Comment: i tried but still same problem ...my server php version is 7.1

Comment: error like this when i use ssl : Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)

Comment: use port 465 for SSL

Comment: yeah i know i used 465 for ssl.same error i dont know why?

Comment: check if your IP is blacklisted and no firewall, are you on ec2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with your SMTP server.
You may try to use another one. 
For debugging propose, I suggest trying to send an email with [Mail Tramp](https://mailtrap.io/).

[image: Mail tramp configuration]

They have a simple way to get the right configuration.
It won't sent any email instead just. It will just show you which email has been send.

Comment: now showing same error      :   Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused)

Comment: @jaz I hope you didn't use my configuration on the screenshot. Cos I have reset the credentials

Comment: i used your configuration on the screenshot

Comment: @jaz login https://mailtrap.io/ on the website and use your owe configuration.

Comment: yeah i tried with my own configuration.its successfully sending email with a warning.

Comment: @jaz, as you see the problem with your SMTP server, try to use another one.

Comment: iam new in yii2 ,, why this config emit errors                                                           'mailer' => [  //Your default mailer
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],

Comment: thanks for all your replays .. but i confused why 'smtp.gmail.com' is not working.

Comment: @jaz 
Well `'username' => 'email@gmail.com'` have you change "username" in your real code?  `'password' => 'password'` -  the same question with password?

Comment: yes i used username my gmail and password my gmail account password